# Make a git uninitialized project the new master branch using a new branch?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a project which I unzipped on my local machine and now I want that project to have its own branch and additionally I want that branch to overwrite the master branch

When I unzipped the project these are the commands which I've made

`git branch` returns "`fatal: not a git repository`"

so this is what I did

`git init`

afterwards

`git branch` didn't return a `fatal...:` it actually didn't return anything

`git remote -v` and `git remote show origin` both didn't return anything

that's when I decided to do

`git remote add origin https://github.com/AquaSolid/Serpent-Works`

now

`git remote -v` actually returned a `fetch` and a `push` for `origin`

`git remote show origin` now prints all the remote branches

Now, I decided to make a new branch

```
git checkout -b revamped
git add -A
git commit -m "Revamped Initial..."
```

Now, `git branch` returns just the line `* revamped` which is written with green letters

I did `git push origin revamped` and that's how I managed to get my `revamped` branch to show on the github repo's website

## This is the error I'm getting

```
>git checkout revamped
Already on 'revamped'
M       .idea/workspace.xml

>git merge --strategy=ours master
merge: master - not something we can merge

>git checkout master
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Comment: You don't have a "master" branch, try `git branch master revamped; git push origin master`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you want to contribute to the github repo (https://github.com/AquaSolid/Serpent-Works) in a new branch `revamped` while keeping the commit history for the existing branches.

And if you want to create the branch `revamped` from the `master` branch, you should **clone the github repo instead of download and unzip**. Since you have already pushed revamped branch into github repo, you can use below steps to recreate `revamped` branch from `master` branch:

```
# In a local directory (such as an empty folder)
git clone https://github.com/AquaSolid/Serpent-Works
cd Serpent-Works
git checkout -B revamped
# Make changes and commit 
git push -u origin revamped -f
```

Now the branch `revamped` is recreated from `master` branches on github.